# Kleisli example needs explicit types and an FlatMap[Option]?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am playing around with the basic [Kleisli example](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/kleisli.html)

```
import cats.data.Kleisli
import cats.FlatMap

val parse = Kleisli[Option, String, Int](
  (s: String) => try {
    Some(s.toInt)
  } catch {
    case _: NumberFormatException => None
  }
)

val reciprocal = Kleisli[Option, Int, Double](
  (i: Int) =>
    if (i == 0)
      None
    else
      Some(1.0 / i))

val c = reciprocal.compose(parse)
```

and two things entagle me

- why do I need to specify explicitly the types [Option,String,Int]? The example code omits them and it must have worked this way too, I guess...
- to evaluate `c` like `c("5")` do I really need to give a `FlatMap[Option]`by hand or is there an implicit import I am missing?

I can add

```
   implicit val optionFlatmap = new FlatMap[Option] {
      override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
      override def map[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: (A) => B): Option[B] = fa.map(f)
    }
```

to evaluate `c("5")`, but isn't there a default implementation for this thing?

Comment: For your second question, I would guess that there's an import missing. Try `import cats.std.all._`

Comment: Right. Thanky you!

Comment: This compiles/runs for me if I leave the types out of the call to `Kleisli`. What version of scala are you using? In a repl or no (it worked for me either way)?

Comment: scala 2.11.8 in an  IntelliJ Scala Worksheet. Btw. I'm still using cats 0.5.0.

Comment: I would recommend not relying on intellij. Try it either in a scala console or via sbt directly. Intellij is known to get some things around type inference wrong. It still works for me using cats 0.5.0.

Comment: If it does turn out to be just an intellij issue, I'd recommend submitting a bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA